# Need to return 5th and 6th value after ^ in oracle string

Tags: string, oracle, escaping

need to return 305 and 2000 ( 5th and 6th value after ^ symbol )  from string  1^1^1^C^15^305^2000^yes in oracle

example String : 1^1^1^C^15^305^2000^yes

o/p: 305 , 2000 in separate columns.

its like length bready piped in a string

Comment: *I need* is not a question - Have you tried anything? Please show the problem with your current attempt.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use the REGEXP_SUBSTR function to extract the 5th and 6th values after the caret (^) symbol from a string.

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(your_column, '[^|]+', 1, 5) AS fifth_value,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(your_column, '[^|]+', 1, 6) AS sixth_value
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: No Sir, we are getting null value.  1^1^1^C^15^305^2000^yes this is the exact string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('1^1^1^C^15^305^2000^yes', '[^^|]+', 1, 5) AS fifthvalue,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('1^1^1^C^15^305^2000^yes', '[^^|]+', 1, 6) AS sixthvalue
FROM dual; 


this worked ..
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's another regex option, with sample data

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1^1^1^C^15^305^2000^yes' from dual)
```

and query itself:

```
  3  SELECT
  4    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '\w+', 1, 6) AS fifth,
  5    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '\w+', 1, 7) AS sixth
  6  FROM test;

FIFTH      SIXTH
---------- ----------
305        2000

SQL>
```

---

Or, a `substr + instr` combination which requires a little bit more typing, but might perform better on large data sets than regular expressions:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1^1^1^C^15^305^2000^yes' from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3  select substr(col, instr(col, '^', 1, 5) + 1,
  4                     instr(col, '^', 1, 6) -  instr(col, '^', 1, 5) - 1
  5               ) fifth,
  6         substr(col, instr(col, '^', 1, 6) + 1,
  7                     instr(col, '^', 1, 7) -  instr(col, '^', 1, 6) - 1
  8               ) sixth
  9  from test;

FIFTH      SIXTH
---------- ----------
305        2000

SQL>
```